# Does boosting being component-wise imply variable selection?

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting, cart, adaboost

I have come across the term "component-wise" in the literature, and I am curious if this means that a model does perform variable selection. And not having this, mean it doesn't perform variable selection.

More specifically, I am currently exploring boosted trees, specifically those introduced by Friedman in his 2001 paper, "Greedy function approximation: A gradient boosting machine." Could one say it's a variable selection model? Equivalently, component-wise boosting?

I appreciate any insights or clarifications on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Fun question (+1). 2. Component-wise learning does not necessitate variable selection but it can be part of it (and that is true in a GBM)! Please see my answer below where I expand on this matter further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fitting formed by the base learners during the training of GBM acts an implicit variable selection indeed; Additionally, the component-wise nature of fitting a GBM is doing some variable selection too but that is not the primary reason why variable selection happens.

Let's clarify things a bit further:
A GBM performs "component-wise" learning in the sense that each new individual base learner tries to counter-balance the mistakes of the previous iterations. This is very obvious in the case of [GAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model)s where via the [back-fitting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backfitting_algorithm) we have component-wise smoothing splines for one selected feature $x_j$ at the time but it extends naturally to GBMs too.
That said, GAMs do *not* perform any variable selection; they have some regularisation properties associated with the cost of the component-wise smoother but do not actually perform variable selection explicitly. A GAM might have a very flat smooth associated with a "useless" feature but that's about it. Some extensions of GAMs do perform variable selection (e.g. see Marra & Wood (2011) *[Practical variable selection for generalized additive models](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947311000491)*) but that's an additional step in the fitting procedure.

Revising now the case of a GBM: the base learners are trees so variable selection is performed in the sense that features that do not contribute to loss function reduction are *not* selected by the *base learners* themselves. Each individual tree performs a weak form of variable selection. In addition, the GBM itself regularises the contribution of each individual base learner based on the shrinkage/learning rate $\alpha$ further stopping a base learner's *potential overfitting* to harm the overall GBM's overall performance. Now, given we usually have dozens, if not hundreds of base learners in our GBM, the tree ensemble as a whole indeed performs performance variable selection via regularisation in two complementary ways: 1. *within* a base learner and 2. *across* base learners when combining them. That said, it is not the component-wise training that primarily leads this but rather fitting itself. (For example, random forests perform a similar "variable selection" procedure, [BART](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3286)s even more.)